# What will happen if a sequence of rectangles with decresing diameter tends to a point?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am studying complex analysis, particularly different versions of Cauchy's theorem. Now while going through the proof of Cauchy's theorem for rectangles I found a concept that a sequence of rectangles with decreasing diameter tends to a point of the initial rectangle I have started with. I know the the concept of sequence in metric spaces where sequence of points of the space tends to some point in that space or some extended space. But how can I relate this concept to above when some nested sets with decreasing diameter tends to a point. What I have thought about it is as follows $:$

Suppose $\{R_n \}$ be nested sequence of rectangles in the complex plane with $\mathrm{diam} (R_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then since $(\mathbb C, ||\ .||_2)$ is complete so by Cantor's intersection theorem we have $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} R_n = \{z^* \}$.  I think it means to say that for a given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \geq k$ we have $||z-z^*|| < \epsilon$ for all $z \in R_n$.

Is it the correct interpretation of such a convergence? I am not sure of that. Please check it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cantor's intersection theorem applies, not because $\mathbb C$ is complete, but because our rectangles $R_n$ are **compact**. [See how the compactness property is used in the proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem#Proof).]

Actually, Cantor's intersection theorem only tells us that $\bigcap_n R_n$ is **non-empty**. We want to show that $\bigcap_n R_n$ contains a **single point**. This is easy to show, and we can do this by following the logic in the third-to-last sentence in your question. Suppose that $\bigcap_n R_n$ contains two distinct points, $z$ and $z'$, and suppose $| z - z'| = \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\rm diam \ }R_n = 0$, there exists an $N$ such that ${\rm diam \ } R_N < \epsilon / 2$. This is a contradiction, because $z, z' \in R_N$ and $|z - z'| = \epsilon > \epsilon / 2 = {\rm diam \ }R_N$.

Having established that $\cap_n R_n$ is a single point, say $\{ z^\star \}$, it is easy to prove that your interpretation of the statement is correct:

> For a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $k \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq k$, we have $|z - z^\star| < \epsilon$ for all $z \in R_n$

Indeed, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $k \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq k$, we have ${\rm diam \ } R_n < \epsilon$. Now suppose $z$ is contained in $R_n$, where $n$ is any integer $\geq k$. Since $z^\star \in \bigcap_n R_n$, we know that $z^\star$ is also contained in $R_n$ for this value of $n$. Therefore, $|z - z'| < {\rm diam \ } R_n < \epsilon$, as required.

Comment: Thank you very much. But is my interpretation above for limit valid?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee The statement that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $k$ such that for all $n \geq k$, $| z - z^\star| < \epsilon$ for all $z \in R_n$ is correct. I'll add it to my answer...

Comment: But in my book I have seen this proof in a complete metric space. What does completeness do then?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee Completeness is not the key idea here. But **all** compact **metric** spaces are complete, so if it's compact, it is also complete, by default. (Or maybe, your book used the assumption that the rectangles are complete AND totally bounded? Because compact $\iff$ complete AND totally bounded.)

Comment: But in the link provided by you the space $S$ is not taken as compact rather it is taken as Hausdorff and any closed subset of a Hausdorff space is compact.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee All metric spaces are Hausdorff! And we don't want $S$ to be compact (remember, $S$ for us is $\mathbb C$). Rather, we need $C_0 \supseteq C_1 \supseteq C_2 \dots$ to be compact (and for us, $C_n$ is the rectangle $R_n$).

Comment: Take for instance $X= \mathbb R \setminus \{0 \}$ and take the sequence $\{[-\frac {1} {n} , \frac {1} {n}] \cap X : n \in \mathbb N \}$. Then it satisfies all conditions stated by you. But what's the intersection?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee Excellent question. In this example, $[-\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n] \cap X = [-\frac 1 n, 0) \cup (0, \frac 1 n]$ is not compact!

Comment: Consider it in the subspace metric.

Comment: But in the subspace topology closed sets takes the form $C \cap X$, Where $C$ is closed in $\mathbb R$. Then why not $[-\frac {1} {n} , \frac {1} {n}] \cap X$ closed in $X$ with subspace topology. What is my mistake?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee Ah sorry, I didn't explain it well... You are of course right that $[-\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n ] \cap X$ is closed in $X$, but not closed in $\mathbb R$. However, what is important for us is whether or not $[\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n] \cap X$ is compact. It is not. Heine-Borel states that a subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact iff it is bounded and closed when considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$. And $[-\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n] \cap X$ is not closed when considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$. So it is not compact.

Comment: But in your link $C_0 ,C_1, \cdots$ are compact subsets of $S$. Suppose $S=X$ here. Then what will happen?

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee As you observed, closedness is a relative property: one would say that $[- \frac 1 n , \frac 1 n] \cap X $ is closed in $X$, but not closed in $\mathbb R$. Compactness is different. Compactness is an absolutely property. One would simply say that $[- \frac 1 n , \frac 1 n]$ is not compact. It doesn't matter whether you're thinking of $[- \frac 1 n, \frac 1 n]$ as a subset of $X$ or of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So to summarise:  (i) $[- \frac 1 n, \frac 1 n] \cap X$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. (ii) $[- \frac 1 n, \frac 1 n] \cap X$ **is** a closed subset of $X$. (iii) $ [-\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n] \cap X$ is not compact (and here, it doesn't matter whether you view it as a subset of $X$ or as a subset of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Kenny Wong. for being with me a long time.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee No problem! I hope this helped.